# Wix bootsrapper packaging

Tags: wix3.5

I am new to Wix and Wix bootstrapper concepts.

In one of requirements, we need to use Wix bootstrapper. Currently the bootstrapper project installs 4 packages.(pacakge 1,package2,package3,package4).
Requirement is when user stops the installation at step 2(while installing the pacakge 2), package 4 still needs to be installed.(Always irrespective of other packages installation success or fail).

Could you please suggest how to perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't particularly tried to do something like that but you could potentially use multiple [RollbackBoundary](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/rollbackboundary.html) in your **Bundle/@Chain** and set the `Vital` attribute as required.